# Function for finding Temperature at Dissolved Oxygen of 3 (TDO3) value across a whole year

Tags: r, function, loops, interpolation, temperature

I am looking to calculate the TDO3 value at every date during the year 2020. I have interpolated data sets of both temperature and dissolved oxygen in 0.25 meter increments from 1m - 22m below the surface between the dates of Jan-1-2020 and Dec-31-2020.

TDO3 is the temperature when dissolved oxygen is 3mg/L. Below are snips of the merged data set.

```
    > print(do_temp, n=85)
# A tibble: 31,110 x 4
   date       depth mean_temp mean_do
   <date>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01  1         2.12  11.6  
 2 2020-01-01  1.25      2.19  11.5  
 3 2020-01-01  1.5       2.27  11.4  
 4 2020-01-01  1.75      2.34  11.3  
 5 2020-01-01  2         2.42  11.2  
 6 2020-01-01  2.25      2.40  11.2  
 7 2020-01-01  2.5       2.39  11.1  
 8 2020-01-01  2.75      2.38  11.1  
 9 2020-01-01  3         2.37  11.0  
10 2020-01-01  3.25      2.41  11.0  
11 2020-01-01  3.5       2.46  11.0  
12 2020-01-01  3.75      2.50  10.9  
13 2020-01-01  4         2.55  10.9  
14 2020-01-01  4.25      2.54  10.9  
15 2020-01-01  4.5       2.53  10.9  
16 2020-01-01  4.75      2.52  11.0  
17 2020-01-01  5         2.51  11.0  
18 2020-01-01  5.25      2.50  11.0  
19 2020-01-01  5.5       2.49  11.0  
20 2020-01-01  5.75      2.49  11.1  
21 2020-01-01  6         2.48  11.1  
22 2020-01-01  6.25      2.49  10.9  
23 2020-01-01  6.5       2.51  10.8  
24 2020-01-01  6.75      2.52  10.7  
25 2020-01-01  7         2.54  10.5  
26 2020-01-01  7.25      2.55  10.4  
27 2020-01-01  7.5       2.57  10.2  
28 2020-01-01  7.75      2.58  10.1  
29 2020-01-01  8         2.60   9.95 
30 2020-01-01  8.25      2.63  10.1  
31 2020-01-01  8.5       2.65  10.2  
32 2020-01-01  8.75      2.68  10.3  
33 2020-01-01  9         2.71  10.5  
34 2020-01-01  9.25      2.69  10.6  
35 2020-01-01  9.5       2.67  10.7  
36 2020-01-01  9.75      2.65  10.9  
37 2020-01-01 10         2.63  11.0  
38 2020-01-01 10.2       2.65  10.8  
39 2020-01-01 10.5       2.67  10.6  
40 2020-01-01 10.8       2.69  10.3  
41 2020-01-01 11         2.72  10.1  
42 2020-01-01 11.2       2.75   9.89 
43 2020-01-01 11.5       2.78   9.67 
44 2020-01-01 11.8       2.81   9.44 
45 2020-01-01 12         2.84   9.22 
46 2020-01-01 12.2       2.83   9.39 
47 2020-01-01 12.5       2.81   9.56 
48 2020-01-01 12.8       2.80   9.74 
49 2020-01-01 13         2.79   9.91 
50 2020-01-01 13.2       2.80  10.1  
51 2020-01-01 13.5       2.81  10.3  
52 2020-01-01 13.8       2.82  10.4  
53 2020-01-01 14         2.83  10.6  
54 2020-01-01 14.2       2.86  10.5  
55 2020-01-01 14.5       2.88  10.4  
56 2020-01-01 14.8       2.91  10.2  
57 2020-01-01 15         2.94  10.1  
58 2020-01-01 15.2       2.95  10.0  
59 2020-01-01 15.5       2.96   9.88 
60 2020-01-01 15.8       2.97   9.76 
61 2020-01-01 16         2.98   9.65 
62 2020-01-01 16.2       2.99   9.53 
63 2020-01-01 16.5       3.00   9.41 
64 2020-01-01 16.8       3.01   9.30 
65 2020-01-01 17         3.03   9.18 
66 2020-01-01 17.2       3.05   9.06 
67 2020-01-01 17.5       3.07   8.95 
68 2020-01-01 17.8       3.09   8.83 
69 2020-01-01 18         3.11   8.71 
70 2020-01-01 18.2       3.13   8.47 
71 2020-01-01 18.5       3.14   8.23 
72 2020-01-01 18.8       3.16   7.98 
73 2020-01-01 19         3.18   7.74 
74 2020-01-01 19.2       3.18   7.50 
75 2020-01-01 19.5       3.18   7.25 
76 2020-01-01 19.8       3.18   7.01 
77 2020-01-01 20         3.18   6.77 
78 2020-01-01 20.2       3.18   5.94 
79 2020-01-01 20.5       3.18   5.10 
80 2020-01-01 20.8       3.18   4.27 
81 2020-01-01 21         3.18   3.43 
82 2020-01-01 21.2       3.22   2.60 
83 2020-01-01 21.5       3.25   1.77 
84 2020-01-01 21.8       3.29   0.934
85 2020-01-01 22         3.32   0.100
# ... with 31,025 more rows
```

https://github.com/TRobin82/WaterQuality

The above link will get you to the raw data.

What I am looking for is a data frame that looks like this but it will have 366 rows for each date during the year.

```
> TDO3
       dates      tdo3
1   2020-1-1  3.183500
2   2020-2-1  3.341188
3   2020-3-1  3.338625
4   2020-4-1  3.437000
5   2020-5-1  4.453310
6   2020-6-1  5.887560
7   2020-7-1  6.673700
8   2020-8-1  7.825672
9   2020-9-1  8.861190
10 2020-10-1 11.007972
11 2020-11-1  7.136880
12 2020-12-1  2.752500
```

However a DO value of a perfect 3 mg/L is not found in the interpolation data frame of DO so I would need the function to find the closest value to 3 without going below then match the depth of that value up with the other data frame for temperature to assign the proper temperature at that depth.

I am assuming the best route to take is a for-loop but not sold on the proper way to go about this question.

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible example with 10-15 rows of data and show the corresponding exact expected output for it so that it is clear what is the goal that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I already have included two snips of what the data looks like and a final example of what I expect the final table to look like so I am not sure what more you'd like me to add. It is hard to show a snip of the example data when it would take 84 rows of data just to show what one day would look like.

Comment: I hope the updates help you answer the question now. Best I can do without over cluttering the question.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's one way of doing it with `tidyverse`-style functions. Note that this code is reproducible because anyone can run it and should get the same answer. It's great that you showed us your data, but it's even better to post the output of `dput()` because then people can load the data and start helping you immediately.

This code does the following:

1. Load the data from the link you provided. But since there were several data files I had to guess which one you meant.
2. Groups the observations by `date`.
3. Puts the observations in increasing order of `mean_do`.
4. Removes rows with values of `mean_do` that are strictly less than 3.
5. Takes the first ordered observation for each date (this will be the one with the lowest value of `mean_do` that is greater than or equal to 3).
6. Rename the column `mean_temp` as `tdo3` since it's the temperature for that date when the dissolved oxygen level was closest to 3mg/L.

```
library(tidyverse)
do_temp <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TRobin82/WaterQuality/main/DateDepthTempDo.csv") %>%
  select(-X1)

do_temp %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  arrange(mean_do) %>%
  filter(mean_do > 3) %>%
  slice_head(n=1) %>%
  rename(tdo3 = mean_temp) %>%
  select(date, tdo3)
```

Here are the results. They're a bit different from the ones you posted, so I'm not sure if I've misunderstood you or if those were just illustrative and not real results.

```
# A tibble: 366 x 2
# Groups:   date [366]
   date        tdo3
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01  3.18
 2 2020-01-02  3.18
 3 2020-01-03  3.19
 4 2020-01-04  3.21
 5 2020-01-05  3.21
 6 2020-01-06  3.21
 7 2020-01-07  3.24
 8 2020-01-08  3.28
 9 2020-01-09  3.27
10 2020-01-10  3.28
# ... with 356 more rows
```

Let me know if you were looking for something else.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I tried to make it way more complicated than need be.... I should have thought about tidyverse but was thinking old school functions. What do you mean "post the output of  `dput()` "? I am new to this whole asking questions on stackoverflow but fairly frequent visitor.

Comment: Glad it helped! Next time, if you run the command `dput(do_temp)` (or maybe `dput(head(do_temp))` it will generate R code that will recreate your input data. That makes it easier for people to help.